# How to hide contacts from Hangouts within Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I use Hangouts within Gmail, I do not use any other client. I would like to know if there is any way to remove or hide contacts from the Hangouts chat list.

I don't want to block the contacts, but don't want to see their name in my chat list. Is there any way to accomplish this, if it is possible at all?

Edit: Hangouts do not have the drop down "more option" that appeared on the old Gchat.

[image]

Comment: Poor Gautam....

Answer (score 18):

Click on the Contact to open the previous Hangout you had with them. Click on the Gear and "archive" the hangout.

Comment: This unfortunately no longer works. I see archived conversations

Comment: I just used it, it works..

Comment: It just worked for me too.

Comment: april 2014, it works

Comment: Works. Bye bye ex girlfriend staring at me all day.

Comment: Thanks, still an option if the chat is opened from Google+

Comment: very difficult UI. this is what UI experts get big bucks for? Had to go to hangouts page, start a chat, then gear and archive.

Answer (score 4):

**In new Hangouts**, the list is no longer a list of contacts, but a list of saved hangouts. Google took a guess to populate the list from the start. As you have real hangouts, they will replace entries on the list.

The only other way is to block the contact, which may bring up another new guesses from Google. This will eventually be replaced as you have real hangouts.

Comment: I don't have the more options drop down list.

Comment: you can revert back to old chat if you want.

Comment: I can, but I'd prefer not to. So it isn't possible to delete from the chat list in new chat?

Comment: The list is no longer a list of contacts, but a list of saved hangouts.Google took a guess to populate the list from the start.  As you have real hangouts, they will replace entries on the list.

Comment: So that would be a no, no way to remove a "hangout" from my list?

Comment: either block the contact or wait till you have real hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse over the contact you no longer want to see in your GChat list, click the down arrow in the lower right-hand side, and click "never show."

Comment: I don't have that option. In the popup that appears on mouseover, an email icon in in the lower right side.

Comment: I'm using the new hangouts chat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the person you want to delete in the chat list box (a contact box will pop up);
2. On the right-hand side, above the contact card, are the options: left arrow / add to my contacts / groups / e-mail / more;
3. Click the *More* tab—a window will open with “Delete” at the top;
4. It will delete all that persons info from your list.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on my chrome hangouts extension.  I have contacts on there that I don't want to block, but I don't want to look at them all day either.  Only way I can hide them by blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot permanently hide them. Some solutions that might help you achieve what you really want, however:

1. At the bottom left of the web page is a little image that seems to be a quotation mark
   inside of a chat bubble. Upon click, **Hangouts is hidden** (but not disabled, and you
   are not logged out or hidden).
2. Click on an entry in the Hangouts box to open the old Hangout. Click the settings
   button (image of a gear). Click the **archive** button. This does not necessarily
   remove the conversation from the list, but many times will. (You cannot empty the list
   by doing this.)